# yslow / reducing jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am using Yslow to review speed.

Problem is i have too many scripts linked, I am trying to reduce repetition:
The problem lies with the first 2 scripts: 
I have tried using just jquery 1.8, even with all its contents from the jquery site.
There is something in the 1.7.2 that is required and i can not figure out.

I have also replaced 1.7 with, jquery-1.3.min and it works.
Yslow gives me a low grade in this area because of the number of HTTP requests, in total with I actually have 9 external Javascript scripts and 5 external css scripts. (3 being for style switching)

If i bump the second script to be first, the autocomplete does not work.

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAOpIKcVcsbojjjFIwnAOSsDwi_lARLp8o&sensor=false"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocate/geometa.js"></script>

     <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
     <script src="js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/downloadxml.js"></script>
```

In short, am trying to reduce the number of external j/s + css.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can consolidate these two

```
<script src="js/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>
```

As the autocomplete is contained in the UI. If you don't want the whole UI just include the autocomplete in your custom build.

Also you could use the public sources for your jQuery, google and company have a distributed network of servers so chances are it's less points from them to your user than from you to your user.

in short try this combination:

```
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAOpIKcVcsbojjjFIwnAOSsDwi_lARLp8o&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geolocate/geometa.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/downloadxml.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, why would you replace 1.7 with 1.3? That's just silly.

Secondly, I'd recommend [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/) to consolidate your JS into one combined and minified file.

Minify offers a `groupsConfig.php` file with an array for your scripts, basically like this: :

```
'js' => array( 
    '//js/jquery-1.7.2.js',
    '//js/jquery-ui.js',
    '//js/libs/geolocate/geometa.js',
    '//js/libs/downloadxml.js'
), 

'css' => array(
  // same thing with css files
)
```

Then you'd only have a single `<script src="/min/?g=js"></script>` tag and a single `<link rel="stylesheet" src="/min/?g=css" />` tag.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to have all the source (js & css) at hand and then minify and combine the source files.

In this way you could have 1 main css file and 1 main js file with an optional extra js file for specific pages (also combined / minified).